# make dep: Nothing to be done for 'depend'

Tags: ios, makefile, pjsip

I have been trying to compile the PJSIP library for an iOS project which needs SIP. Following [this](http://gaurav-iphone.blogspot.de/2011/09/compiling-pjsip.html) tutorial, I have been able to run the configure-iphone script. The next step would to run the make dep for the dependencies, but sadly it fails bcs of some error, unknown to me. I have also tried to edit the makefile, so it points directly to the file, but I still get the error, so it can find the file.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Samples.mak depend
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `depend'.
```

is the error I get.

The make file:

```
include ../../build.mak
include $(PJDIR)/build/common.mak

export LIBDIR := ../lib
export BINDIR := ../bin

RULES_MAK := $(PJDIR)/build/rules.mak
SAMPLES_MAK := $(PJDIR)/pjsip-apps/build/Samples.mak


###############################################################################
# Gather all flags.
#
export _CFLAGS  := $(CC_CFLAGS) $(OS_CFLAGS) $(HOST_CFLAGS) $(M_CFLAGS) \
           $(PJ_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CC_INC)../../pjsip/include \
           $(CC_INC)../../pjlib/include \
           $(CC_INC)../../pjlib-util/include \
           $(CC_INC)../../pjnath/include \
           $(CC_INC)../../pjmedia/include
export _CXXFLAGS:= $(_CFLAGS) $(CC_CXXFLAGS) $(OS_CXXFLAGS) $(M_CXXFLAGS) \
           $(HOST_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS)
export _LDFLAGS := $(CC_LDFLAGS) $(OS_LDFLAGS) $(M_LDFLAGS) $(HOST_LDFLAGS) \
           $(APP_LDFLAGS) $(APP_LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS)

###############################################################################
# Defines for building PJSUA
#
export PJSUA_SRCDIR = ../src/pjsua
export PJSUA_OBJS += $(OS_OBJS) $(M_OBJS) $(CC_OBJS) $(HOST_OBJS) \
            main.o pjsua_app.o pjsua_app_cli.o pjsua_app_common.o \
            pjsua_app_config.o pjsua_app_legacy.o
export PJSUA_CFLAGS += $(PJ_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
export PJSUA_CXXFLAGS += $(PJ_CXXFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
export PJSUA_LDFLAGS += $(PJ_LDFLAGS) $(PJ_LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS)
export PJSUA_EXE:=pjsua-$(TARGET_NAME)$(HOST_EXE)


###############################################################################
# Defines for building pjsystest
#
export PJSYSTEST_SRCDIR = ../src/pjsystest
export PJSYSTEST_OBJS += $(OS_OBJS) $(M_OBJS) $(CC_OBJS) $(HOST_OBJS) \
            systest.o main_console.o
export PJSYSTEST_CFLAGS += $(PJ_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
export PJSYSTEST_CXXFLAGS += $(PJ_CXXFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
export PJSYSTEST_LDFLAGS += $(PJ_LDFLAGS) $(PJ_LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS)
export PJSYSTEST_EXE:=pjsystest-$(TARGET_NAME)$(HOST_EXE)


export CC_OUT CC AR RANLIB HOST_MV HOST_RM HOST_RMDIR HOST_MKDIR OBJEXT LD LDOUT

TARGETS := $(PJSUA_EXE) $(PJSYSTEST_EXE) samples

all: $(TARGETS)

swig:
    $(MAKE) -C ../src/swig

doc:

dep: depend
distclean: realclean

.PHONY: all dep depend clean realclean distclean
.PHONY: $(TARGETS)
.PHONY: $(PJSUA_EXE) $(PJSYSTEST_EXE)

pjsua: $(PJSUA_EXE)
$(PJSUA_EXE):
    $(MAKE) -f $(RULES_MAK) APP=PJSUA app=pjsua $(subst /,$(HOST_PSEP),$(BINDIR)/$@)
    @if echo "$(TARGET_NAME)" | grep -q "apple-darwin_ios$$"; then \
      for F in $(filter %$(TARGET_NAME).a,$(PJ_LIBXX_FILES)); do \
        if test -f $$F; then \
          tmp=`echo $${F##*/} | sed -e "s/\-$(TARGET_NAME)\.a/.a/"`; \
          ln -sf $$F ../src/pjsua/ios/$$tmp; \
        fi; \
      done; \
    fi;

pjsystest: $(PJSYSTEST_EXE)
$(PJSYSTEST_EXE):
    $(MAKE) -f $(RULES_MAK) APP=PJSYSTEST app=pjsystest $(subst /,$(HOST_PSEP),$(BINDIR)/$@)

samples:
    $(MAKE) -f $(SAMPLES_MAK)

.PHONY: pjsua.ko
pjsua.ko:
    $(MAKE) -f $(RULES_MAK) APP=PJSUA app=pjsua $(subst /,$(HOST_PSEP),$(LIBDIR)/$@)

clean depend realclean:
    $(MAKE) -f $(RULES_MAK) APP=PJSUA app=pjsua $@
    $(MAKE) -f $(RULES_MAK) APP=PJSYSTEST app=pjsystest $@
    #Problem happens in the next row!
    $(MAKE) -f $(SAMPLES_MAK) $@
    @if test "$@" = "depend"; then \
      echo '$(BINDIR)/$(PJSUA_EXE): $(APP_LIB_FILES)' >> .pjsua-$(TARGET_NAME).depend; \
      echo '$(BINDIR)/$(PJSYSTEST_EXE): $(APP_LIB_FILES)' >> .pjsystest-$(TARGET_NAME).depend; \
    fi
    @if echo "$(TARGET_NAME)" | grep -q "apple-darwin_ios$$"; then \
      for F in $(filter %$(TARGET_NAME).a,$(PJ_LIBXX_FILES)); do \
        tmp=`echo $${F##*/} | sed -e "s/\-$(TARGET_NAME)\.a/.a/"`; \
        rm -f ../src/pjsua/ios/$$tmp; \
      done; \
    fi;
```

Like I said, I added the SAMPLES_MAK variable, but sadly it didn't help. I also found out which line is giving me the error, it's close to the end of the file `$(MAKE) -f $(SAMPLES_MAK) $@`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [official](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone) documentation for building. It works 100% for all current architectures for iOS.

Comment: The steps are pretty same, so that doesn't help me either. I have opened the Samples.mak and there is a row with `depend:` and nothing is there. Should I maybe just out comment that and go on? Bcs it seems like there are no dependencies.

Comment: I don't know why you want to make only that file. In official documentation after configure they run `make dep && make clean && make` without specifying any files.

Comment: Yes. And if I do make dep I get an error stating that in Samples.mak there is nothing to depend

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means you've accidentally (?) created a file or directory  named `depend` in your working directory.  So, make sees that file or directory and, since the makefile doesn't list any prerequisites of the `depend` target, it believe the target is up to date.

This is why generally you declare these types of helper targets to be `.PHONY`, but apparently that makefile doesn't do this.

Comment: I have fixed the problem by moving the part with `SAMPLE_MAK` out of the  `clean depend realclean` in a seperate `clean realclean` part so it wont be called when I do `make dep`